# How to plot a portion of a curve and the area under it

Tags: plotting

I want to display the portion of the curve `Plot[Exp[-x^2], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, Filling -> Bottom,  GridLines -> {{0.6}, {0.7}}]` (and the area under it) to the right of `x=0.6`.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
plot = Plot[{Exp[-x^2], ConditionalExpression[Exp[-x^2], .6 <= x <= 1]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> Blue, 
 Filling -> {2 -> Bottom}, 
 GridLines -> {{0.6}, {0.7}}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
Area @ BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics @ plot
```

> ```
> 0.211665
> ```

Alternatively,

```
Integrate[Exp[-x^2], {x, .6, 1}]
```

> ```
> 0.211671
> ```

Comment: The area is `Area[ImplicitRegion[
   1/E <= y <= Exp[-x^2] && 3/5 <= x <= 1, {x, y}]] // Simplify` which evaluates to `-(2/(5*E)) - (1/2)*Sqrt[Pi]*Erf[3/5] + (1/2)*Sqrt[Pi]*Erf[1]` or approximately `0.0645188`